# Filepath search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a filepath in the following format:

```
/Volumes/new/tom/my123file_movie+new-release.mov
```

I want to be able to search the raw case-insensitive string to match the following search terms:

```
/Volumes/new/tom/my123file_movie+new-release.mov # [the full string]
new 123file # [case insensitive inner strings]
ov 12 mov new _movie+new- [case insensitive inner strings]
```

What would be the correct index settings to do this? Currently what I have is the following, but it is pretty naive:

```
body = {
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "lowercase": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": ["lowercase"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "path": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "lowercase"},

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not answering your question, but one alternative approach would be to modify the string on the search itself. For example, if you need to remove characters such as `/-_.:`, you could do so with something like:

```
>>> search = ' '.join(re.sub(r':|\/|\.|-|_', ' ', 'file://THIS_IS-MY-SEARCH.STRING').split())
>>> search
'file THIS IS MY SEARCH STRING'
```

It might be ugly (and you can remove excess whitespace) but it should accomplish the same as the above.